# Why won't TryParse() work when I try to convert a string to an int?

Tags: c#, structure, tryparse

I am a beginner student and I have a homework assignment involving structures, I'm also using Visual Studio 2017.

I made a structure and now I'm trying to assign input from a textbox to a field of an instance of the created structure. I'm trying to assign a string from a textbox to a field of the int data type from the struct I created.

When I try to convert the string from the textbox using the TryParse() method, it doesn't work. VS tells me that the name 'varName' doesn't exist in the current context. What does this mean? How can I go about fixing this issue?

```
     enum Month
        {
            January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
        }

        struct Person
        {
            public string name;

            public string jobTitle;

            public Month month;

            public int day;

            public int year;
        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Month month = (Month)Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), monthDropDown.Text);
            Person user;

            user.name = nameTextBox.Text;
            user.jobTitle = jobTitleTextBox.Text;
            user.month = month;
            user.day = int.TryParse(dayTxtBox.Text, out day); //here I'm trying to use the TryParse method but it gives me the error the name 'day' doesn't exist in the current context
            user.year = int.TryParse(yearTextBox.Text, out year); //here I'm trying to use the TryParse method but it gives me the error the name 'year' doesn't exist in the current context
        }
```

Comment: Does `user.day = int.TryParse(dayTxtBox.Text, out var day); ` work?

Comment: @nvoigt: Nice of you to take `(C#)` off the end of the title, but it's still 100% wrong.  The conversion is string->int, not int->string, and the function being attempted is `TryParse`, not `ToString`.  One wonders if the husk of a previous question has been reused or something.

Comment: @ChristianBerumen, How did you come up with that title? It doesn't match your question in any way.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ops, good catch.

Comment: OT a struct with mutable fields is not the best design choice. Better make it a class

Comment: Can we please confirm, this is Winforms? Right?

Comment: @JeremyThompson, this is winfoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method **tries** to parse the string into an `int`. It might fail. So it does *not* return an `int`. It returns a `bool` to signal whether parsing has actually succeeded. So you need to be prepared for the result not being usable as an `int`:

```
if(int.TryParse(dayTxtBox.Text, out var day))
{
    user.day = day;
}
else
{
    /// put code here to handle what should happen if user entered "hello" for example
}
```

Alternatively, if this is homework and a few of these concepts have not been covered yet in your course, you could simplify it and assume the user never makes mistakes and always enters a correct number (warning: not a real life scenario):

```
user.day = int.Parse(dayTxtBox.Text);
```

Comment: I don't agree, I won't downvote or anything but this is the wrong use of UI design. Even if my advice of a calendar isn't available a dropdown list with 28,29,30 & 31 items depending on month is the WTG as it doesn't need validation.

Comment: @JeremyThompson you realize this is a homework assignment right? We aren’t talking about UI design here, this is basic Compiler errors. You are right, but you are probably 6 months ahead of the OPs class and asking people to skip ahead instead of following the class is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare those variable that you want to use as `out` parameter in `TryParse` method

In your case you used `out day` and `out year` but you need to tell the compiler what the type of `day` and `year` variable are.

You can use the ternary operator, if your input success to parse then it return parsed value to `user.day` and `user.year` otherwise simply returns 0.

```
user.day = int.TryParse(dayTxtBox.Text, out int day) ? day : 0;
user.year = int.TryParse(yearTextBox.Text, out int year) ? year : 0;
```

Or more simply with `if....else` block,

```
if (int.TryParse(dayTxtBox.Text, out int day))
{
    user.day = day;
}
else
{
    user.day = 0; //Or set any value whatever you want when parsing fail
}
```

Comment: It does not return the default. How would you know it failed then, as the default is a valid input?

Comment: @nvoigt,  if you pass value that are not integer like `xyz` then your `out` parameter will gives  you intialized value of int like 0

Comment: Ah... no? Please paste your code into Visual Studio and correct the obvious compiler errors.

Comment: And the reasons why *all* those `Try...` methods do not work that way is that you would not know how to differentiate between user input of "0" and "error", one being valid and one not.

Comment: @nvoigt: The `out` parameter is definitely assigned no matter whether the function returns `true` or `false`.  The compiler won't let you return normally (you can `throw`) from a function with an `out` parameter without having assigned it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't doubt that. It's just that `default(int)` as the out parameters value is no indication of failure, only the return value actually indicates whether it failed or not. There is no way to know whether the out parameter was set to `default(int)` because of a failure or to `0` because of success.

Comment: @BenVoigt You may want to look at the answer at the time of my comment, I was quite literally talking about the return value, not the out parameter in my first and second comments.

Comment: Ah, er-sho's comment wording (the `out` parameter will give you an initialized value, true) didn't accurately reflect the previous version of the answer (expecting the "initial" value of the `out` parameter -- there is no such thing, `ref` is needed -- to be returned).  Regardless, the logic of the current answer could be accomplished more simply by `int.TryParse(dayTxtBox.Text, out user.day);`

Answer (score 0):

I could give you code but the best solution is to use a control you don't need to validate. Typing a day in a TextBox is so 1990's.

It's best I recommend a calendar control bound to a `DateTime theDate { get; set; }` field.

Comment: While true, I cannot imagine this being very helpful to a question that is obviously artificially constrained to what the OP is working with right now. You don't even know which UI technology they use and if a bindable calendar control is available.

Comment: @nvoight `private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` makes it pretty easy to.assume WimForms or Asp.Net WebFroms.